# Catching WMI exceptions internally with Delphi

Tags: delphi, exception, try-catch, wmi

I was asked to make an application (in pascal/delphi 2007) that can be used to reboot remote machines (running XP) based on user input. I've made a similar piece of software in C#/.NET2.0. I am new to Pascal/Delphi, however I managed to translate my code for the most part. The systems that this application will run on do not always have .NET unfortunately.

To determine if the remote machine is active, I attempt a ping. The ping uses WMI to connect to the computer, which requires a username/password.

Is there a better way to test if a remote machine is on the network? I've done research and pinging seems to be the best bet in this scenario. Unfortunately the remote machines I am rebooting have their drives write-protected so I cannot create a server/client scenario.

If the remote machine is not connected on the network, the application throws an exception for Access Denied.

In C#, I could do something along the lines of

```cs
try {
    //WMI code to connect to remote machine
}
catch (Exception Except)
{
    WrteExceptionToLog(Except);
}
```

In Delphi, I attempted the following:

```pascal
try
  //WMI code to connect to remote machine
except
  on E: Exception do
    WrteExceptionToLog(E);
end;
```

Although that type of try/except works in most other parts of the code it doesn't seem to handle WMI calls. It does not catch the exception and it goes straight to the compiler catching it as a EOleException. Being desperate, I tried

```pascal
try
  //WMI code to connect to remote machine
except
  on E: EOleException do
    WrteExceptionToLog(E);
end;
```

This resulted the same as the exception.

I did attempt to implement a universal 'catch-all' exception handler. This worked, but after logging the error, it would crash the application. I did not pursue this any further. The logging function works fine outside of the universal exception handler.

```pascal
function pingMachine(const Address: string; Retries, BufferSize: Word): Integer;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
  i              : Integer;
  mResult        : Integer;
  PacketsReceived: Integer;
  Minimum        : Integer;
  Maximum        : Integer;
  Average        : Integer;
  test: Integer;
begin
  PacketsReceived := 0;
  Minimum         := 0;
  Maximum         := 0;
  Average         := 0;

  mResult := -1;

  try
    FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');

    //WMI exception below when remote machine is offline
    FWMIService := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(Address, 'root\CIMV2',
                    'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');

    //code to do the actual ping... 

  except
    on E: EOleException do
    begin
      LogFiles.NewException(E);
    end;

    on E: Exception do
    begin
      LogFiles.NewException(E);
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: `try/except` is the correct solution. It handles COM/OLE errors just fine (in your examples, you are missing the `except` keyword, though). If you are having problems, it has to be in code you have not shown. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have updated the OP with a code snippet from the function.

Comment: Did you test this outside the IDE? The IDE halts by default on exceptions, though you can make exceptions for this in the debugger's settings

Comment: FWIW, since I assume Binary didn't really forget `except` in his code, I added except where necessary. That was not causing the problem.

Comment: @Marco: you could be right. The fact that the IDE stops on an exception doesn't mean it is not handled, it simply means the IDE warns you before the exceptin handler is entered. This does not influence program flow. Just press [Continue] and the exception handler is invoked.

Comment: I was using the 'Run without debugging' function inside of the IDE. This still showed behavior I was not anticipating. I just ran it from the exe with the IDE closed, and it seems to be handled properly Thanks for the suggestion @Marco !

Comment: @Marco: "The IDE halts by default on *exceptions*, though you can make *exceptions* for this". Heheh, excepting exceptions?

Comment: To not confuse the original poster with Rudy's joke: Yes, exceptions in the debugger handling of the program's exceptions. So different uses of the word exception.

Comment: @Rudy: For future reference, it's not acceptable here to edit code in questions except to correct formatting. If the OP didn't forget except in the code, the OP should edit to correct it. It is the OP's responsibility to post the proper code, and it's definitely not safe to *assume* that it was actually correct and just posted wrong. I can find you Meta SO references that discuss not editing code in questions if you need them.

Comment: @Ken: ah, OK. Sorry. No need to find references, I believe you. But I did not assume, I deduced it from his comments (and his code compiled, it did just not run as expected). Shall I roll it back?

Comment: @Rudy: It's been edited again after yours, so I'd leave it. Just something to keep in mind in the future. Doesn't matter if you can deduce it from the comments; it's still the OP's responsibility to properly post the code. If they choose not to, it's on them. Editing code in questions can drastically change (or hide) the actual issue, and it can also negate existing answers and cost those posters rep.

Comment: I know what the effect of code that is not actually copied and pasted can be: it possibly obfuscates the real problem. Won't do that again.

Comment: You are connecting to the remote machine to be able to ping it to test if you can connect to that machine? I think you are confused.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, you are correct. I did this originally when translating from .NET to pascal. I've since removed the ping class. In the .NET version, I had no need to connect to a remote system to ping it. So I could ping a remote machine and determine if I could communicate with it or not prior to attempting a WMI reboot.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the OP).*

The issue was not code related. Running the application outside the IDE allowed the exception to be handled properly.